# strcmp doesn't return 0 for 2 exact files

Tags: c, strcmp

i wrote a code with c, that reads from 2 files, and than i compare the 2 buffers with strcmp. for some strings, even when i read from the exact same file, strcmp returns !=0

anybody has an idea why?

here is the relevent part from the code:

```
read_max[0]= read(fdin[0],read_buf,read_offset) ;
read_max[1]=read(fdin[1],read_buf2,read_offset);

    if(strcmp(read_buf,read_buf2)){
        same=1;
    }
```

i tried to check for answers on this forum and in others, but the only answer i found was for the case of '\n' that is added.
as i wrote in the headline, the problem isnwt that it doesn't get inside  the if, but that it does( because it doesn't return 0)!
its not the case here. the way of writing the strings are the same.
in edition, sometimes strcmp works properly.

for example, if the file starts with whitespace or \n, it goes wrong.
thank you!

Comment: Return value of `0` is falsey in C.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Pare your files down to a single line -- as short as possible -- that produces the error, and add it to your question. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `read()` doesn't necessarily write a *string* to the destination. You, as the programmer, are responsible to manage that so that you can send the data to `strcmp()`.

Comment: What pmg wrote: If you want to read lines from a text file, use `fgets`. The functions `fread` and `read` are for reading a fixed number of raw bytes.

Comment: i editted my question. 
i'm not allowed to use something else, only read().

thank you for answering!!

Comment: `strcmp()` always works properly. However its behavior depends on the data provided so if you are not seeing an expected behavior then the problem will be with the data you are providing. It could be embedded binary zero characters or a difference in the string lengths or not a terminating binary zero character. Remember that a binary zero is the string terminator in C. You may need to use the `strncmp()` function which takes an additional max character count. Also you need to check that your data is actually `char` text characters and not UTF-16 UNICODE or multi-byte characters.

Comment: Did you check if both `read` operations return the same amount of data? Did they read all the data expected?

Comment: `strcmp` needs `NUL` terminated strings. From your piece of code we cannot see if you ensure the strings you compare are NUL terminated. If they are not `NUL` terminated, the behaviour of `strcmp` is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

You should use memcmp instead:

```
if(read_max[0] != read_max[1] || memcmp(read_buf,read_buf2, read_max[0]) != 0) {
    /* Buffers are different */
}
```

Comment: no, i want it to get inside only if theyr'e different.

thank you for your answer!

Comment: Use strncmp() instead of strcmp()

Comment: You set `same` to a true-value if it is not same?

Comment: andriy -whats the diifrence between strnvmp and strcmp beside the fact of where the comparsion starts?

Comment: gerhard- i don't use same as boolian, i use it to get a sum. if theyr'e diffrent i need the sum to be +1.

Comment: strncmp() and memcmp() take buffer length as an argument. Since you do not know how many bytes will be returned by read() and if those bytes will be NULL-terminated, you better use strncmp() or memcmp() to limit your comparison up to the number of bytes you just read.

Comment: strncmp did solve the problem, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The function `srtcmp()` returns 0 when two strings are equal.

Change code like this:

```
if(!strcmp(read_buf,read_buf2)){
    same=1;
}
```

or

```
if(strcmp(read_buf,read_buf2) == 0){
    same=1;
}
```